# Php File get stop working

Tags: php

All of a sudden my php file get is giving me a 503 error .Can anybody knows why and is there another method to that.

```
php $URL = "http://www.website.com/foo.html"; 
$a =file_get_contents("$URL"); echo ($a);
```

Answer (score 3):

***Sol 1 :***

```
function get_http_response_code($url) {
    $headers = get_headers($url);
    return substr($headers[0], 9, 3);
}
if(get_http_response_code('http://somenotrealurl.com/notrealpage') != "404"){
    file_get_contents('http://somenotrealurl.com/notrealpage');
}else{
    echo "error";
}
```

***Sol 2 :***

With such commands in PHP, you can prefix them with an @ to suppress such warnings.

```
@file_get_contents('http://somenotrealurl.com/notrealpage');
```

`file_get_contents()` returns FALSE if a failure occurs, so if you check the returned result against that then you can handle the failure

```
$pageDocument = @file_get_contents('http://somenotrealurl.com/notrealpage');

if ($pageDocument === false) {
    // Handle error
}
```

***Sol 3 :***

While file_get_contents is very terse and convenient, I tend to favour the Curl library for better control. Here's an example.

```
function fetchUrl($uri) {
    $handle = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_URL, $uri);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POST, false);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, false);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);

    $response = curl_exec($handle);
    $hlength  = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
    $httpCode = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    $body     = substr($response, $hlength);

    // If HTTP response is not 200, throw exception
    if ($httpCode != 200) {
        throw new Exception($httpCode);
    }

    return $body;
}

$url = 'http://some.host.com/path/to/doc';

try {
    $response = fetchUrl($url);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    error_log('Fetch URL failed: ' . $e->getMessage() . ' for ' . $url);
}
```

Comment: you can mark answer as accepted if it is.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, that you have a right URL? The HTTP-Code 503 is the code for "Service Temporarily Unavailable". 
Maybe check it with the function `get_headers($url);`